# Series from $1,2,3,4$ that sum to $n$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

$B_n$  is the number of series build from 1,2,3,4 and sum to n.

prove that :
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n x^n =\sum_{s=0}^\infty (x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^s $$

Comment: You should add your attempt to the question.

Comment: @amir familiar with [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)?

Comment: @Aryadeva oh sorry thats my first time publishing here

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin i tried generating function but i didn't get anything. i think it's exponential generating function because the order is important

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: 
Consider a bijection, when sum of $a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_s$ corresponds to taking (and multiplying up then) $\displaystyle x^{a_k}$ from $k$th parenthesis of RHS's $s$th term $$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)\cdot (x+x^2+x^3+x^4)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x+x^2+x^3+x^4).$$ How can you now argue that the desired equality holds?